# How to fetch ofbject in MYSQLI

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a problem in fetching a data. Here i try to select a certain table an
displayed it using print_r. 
But it's output is quite new to me.

```
  $db = JFactory::getDbo(); 
      $query = $db->getQuery(true);

      $query = "SELECT * FROM test_data_base WHERE user_id = '1' ";


      $db->setQuery($query); 
      $result = $db->execute();

 //      while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
 //         echo $row->field_count;
    //     echo $row->num_rows;
    // }

      echo "<pre>";
      print_r($result);
      echo "</pre>";
```

The output is like this.

```
mysqli_result Object
(
    [current_field] => 0
    [field_count] => 9
    [lengths] => 
    [num_rows] => 1
    [type] => 0
)
```

I was expecting that it should be an array but it shows an object which is new to me. My question is how do i fetch and display a certain value. Such as user_id?

Comment: Probably the joomla documentation would help you if you only read it.

Answer (score 0):

Using Object Syntax
Rather than use mysql_fetch_object($result) you should be using the object syntax

```
$row = $result->fetch_object();
```

To access your fields you again use the object syntax

```
$row->current_field
$row->field_count
```

Using Array syntax
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

```
$row = $result->fetch_array();
```

To access your fields as an array

```
$row['current_field']
$row['field_count]
```